# Django task processing

Tags: django

How would you process tasks in django, say there is an event only to processed once daily, weekly, monthly. (besides cron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://celeryproject.org/

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean, besides cron? cron is exactly how you would do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a very simple tool: [django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) (runs inside of Django application thread).

If you do this please see my answer: [Django: Getting Django-cron Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127758/django-getting-django-cron-running)