# Django: Getting Django-cron Running

Tags: django, django-cron

I am trying to get [Django-cron](http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/) running, but it seems to only run after hitting the site once. I am using Virtualenv.

Any ideas why it only runs once?

On my PATH, I added the location of django_cron: '/Users/emilepetrone/Workspace/zapgeo/zapgeo/django_cron'

My cron.py file within my Django app:

```
from django_cron import cronScheduler, Job

from products.views import index

class GetProducts(Job):

    run_every = 60

    def job(self):
        index()

cronScheduler.register(GetProducts)

class GetLocation(Job):

    run_every = 60

    def job(self):
        index()

cronScheduler.register(GetLocation)
```

Comment: In my case it runs regularly (second time without hitting), not according to **run_every** but to *much more interval*. May the tool requires a *minimum interval*?

Comment: I found the second reason. Please view my answer again.

Answer (score 2):

***The first possible reason***

There is a variable in **django_cron/base.py**:

```
# how often to check if jobs are ready to be run (in seconds)
# in reality if you have a multithreaded server, it may get checked
# more often that this number suggests, so keep an eye on it...
# default value: 300 seconds == 5 min
polling_frequency = getattr(settings, "CRON_POLLING_FREQUENCY", 300)
```

So, the minimal interval of checking for time to start your task is **polling_frequency**. You can change it by setting in *settings.py* of your project:

```
CRON_POLLING_FREQUENCY = 100 # use your custom value in seconds here
```

To start a job hit your server at least one time after starting Django web server.

***The second possible reason***

Your job has an error and it is not queued (*queued* flag is set to 'f' if your job raises an exception). In this case it stores in field 'queued' of table 'django_cron_job' string value 'f'. You can test it making the query:

`select queued from django_cron_job;`

If you change the code of your job the field may stay as 'f'. So, if you correct the error of your job you should manually set in queued field: 't'. Or the flag **executing** in the table **django_cron_cron** is 't'. It means that your app. server was stopped when your task was in progress. In this case you should manually set it into 'f'.